# How to set a Transparent GUI in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

So I just want a very simple transparent background for my GUI, the only purpose of this is just to have some fun with my brother like basically putting an invisible wall between the pc and him, no apps or anything like that, this is my current code-

```
!Z::
Gui, -Border -Caption +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, color , black  ; Alt + Z
Gui, Show, x0 y0 w%A_ScreenWidth% h%A_ScreenHeight%
Return
!X::
Gui, destroy  ; Alt + X
Return
```

Now all I want to do is make the GUI transparent instead of black
I'm not too familiar with code or anything and am very new
I've googled around but wasn't able to understand how to do it
Please help

Thanks In Advance

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/61388-transparent-gui/

Answer (score 1):

```
!Z::
Gui, -Border -Caption +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, color , black  ; Alt + Z
Gui, Show, x0 y0 w%A_ScreenWidth% h%A_ScreenHeight%, barrier
WinSet, Transparent, 0, barrier
Return
!X::
Gui, destroy  ; Alt + X
Return
```